# Unable to build SASS in Sublime (Ruby/SASS Gem Installed)

Tags: css, ruby, sass, rubygems, sublimetext2

I've been trying to setup my workflow for Sass in Sublime Text 2 (Mac OSX). I already have Ruby and the SASS gem installed on my Mac.

I have the SASS Build package installed and the SASS Syntax Highlighter package installed all fine.

When opening a SCSS file and selecting Tools > Build I get the following error in the console:

```
env: ruby: No such file or directory
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 127]
```

I have double checked ruby and sass are installed by issuing `which sass` and `which ruby` which both return the install paths.

```
/Users/rose/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/sass
/Users/rose/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby
```

My SASS.sublime-build script is pointing to `/Users/rose/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/`

Ive tried re-installing ruby using RVM and re-installing the sass gem but I am still getting the same error.

Can anyone advise what could be causing this?

**EDIT** (Adding SASS.sublime-build script)

```
{

    "cmd": ["sass", "--update", "$file:${file_path}/css/${file_base_name}.css", "--stop-on-error", "--no-cache"],
    "selector": "source.sass, source.scss",
    "line_regex": "Line ([0-9]+):",

    "osx":
    {
        "path": "/Users/rose/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
    },

    "windows":
    {
        "shell": "true"
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the contents of your `.sublime-build` file.